# I'm not getting the correct output when I encode the bytes back to base64

Tags: python-3.x, integer, output, byte, base64url

```
import base64

# Decoding Byte
byte = base64.decodebytes(b'Gcmtb8==')

# Getting an int from the byte
Number = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder="big")

# From Int to bytes again (For Testing & confirmation)
Decoded = int.to_bytes(Number,4,byteorder="big")

# Encoding back to base64_urlsafe
encode = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(Decoded)

print("""
Test 1

Decoded to byte: {}
Number from byte: {}
Byte from number: {}
Output: {}
""".format(byte,Number,Decoded,encode))
```

> *Output
> Test 1
> Decoded to byte: b'\x19\xc9\xado'
> Number from byte: 432647535
> Byte from number: b'\x19\xc9\xado'
> Output: b'Gcmtbw=='
> | The Output I want
> Test 1
> Decoded to byte: b'\x19\xc9\xado'
> Number from byte: 432647535
> Byte from number: b'\x19\xc9\xado'
> Output: b'Gcmtb8=='*

Comment: So you wonder why the string changes from `Gcmtb8==` to `Gcmtbw==`. The first 4 characters encode 3 bytes, then  you have 12 bits left (each Base64 character encodes 6 bits) but only need 8 of them for the 4th byte of data. So the last 4 bits of the last character are insignificant. 8 means 111100 in Base64 encoding and w means 110000. So the first 2 bits are the same, the last 4 are not relevant.  See also my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492009/jwt-token-decoding-even-when-the-last-character-of-the-signature-is-changed)

Comment: I'm still confused... is there even a way I can get that output?

Comment: The important part to understand is, that in Base64 with 6 bits per character there are often unused bits at the end of the Base64 string. In your case, the encoder just needs a Base64 character that has the first two bits set to 1 while the last 4 don't matter, which can be fulfilled by all of the last 16 Base64 characters (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table_from_RFC_4648), and `w` is the first one. Why should the encode choose any other character if only the first 2 bits matter?