# Unexpected behavior: access token modification don't seems to affect API call

Tags: django-rest-framework-simplejwt

EDIT - 2023-10-11

To answer @jps
Imagine I have registered a user and generated access/refresh pairs tokens using DRF and Simple JWT

```
{
    "refresh": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY5NzY0MjMzOCwiaWF0IjoxNjk2OTUxMTM4LCJqdGkiOiIwMjRkMzYyYzAwMTY0ZGJmYjFjMjk1NDNmZGYwMWVhNyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJxcl9jb2RlIjpudWxsfQ.kENNaskSUld82jPewY3602uhb1xQ00aWiRXEAcIpwEw",
    "access": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjk3NjQyMzM4LCJpYXQiOjE2OTY5NTExMzgsImp0aSI6IjBiODEwZDhiMmFhYTQwM2RiNTIzMjliZjdhNzYxOWFhIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsInFyX2NvZGUiOm51bGx9.Cfi1jo1YxTUhvfUgUnafcn-ufQyY8DzWb9UYXTMl09w"
}
```

Now, I want to call a project API using the access token. It works.
But If I modify the access token (just to test), replacing the last "w" character with "x" for example, token is still valid and my API call will works.

Maybe I'm wrong but this should not works, right?
Or the fact that token is still valid (for 8 days), it is the expected behavior?

---

I use Django Rest Framework and Simple JWT to generate access/refresh token used in other API call.
But for example, if I DROP database and CREATE new database, old generated access/refresh token still works to authenticate and call API?
If I modify generated access token, authentication will also achieve if token has a valid structure?

Maybe I misunderstand Simple JWT?
In my understanding, when I generate a access/refresh pairs token I should not be able to modify them?

```
# settings.py
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=8),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=8),
    "TOKEN_OBTAIN_SERIALIZER": "rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers.MyTokenObtainPairSerializer",
}

# urls.py
path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),

# views.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

# serializer.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['username'] = user.username
        profile = user.profile
        token['qr_code'] = profile.qr_code

        return token
```

Comment: I think I don't really understand your question. How is the database related to the verification of the token? And then you wrote:  *If I modify generated access token, authentication will also achieve if token has a valid structure?* - Why do you think you could modify the token and still get authenticated? (sidenote: actually authorized would be correct tern here)

Comment: @jps: I have EDITED my post to add an example

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's important to write all the details. Modifying a token can mean anything, but now it's clear that you mean just one special case. I have already written a detailed answer about that specific case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JWT token decoding even when the last character of the signature is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492009/jwt-token-decoding-even-when-the-last-character-of-the-signature-is-changed)

Comment: Hi @jps: the behavior is as described in the post; thanks for explanaition